# Using fit fit_resamples() to train and compare LDA and QDA models in R

Tags: r, machine-learning

I am defining an LDA classifier using

```
LDA <- discrim_regularized(frac_common_cov = 1) %>% set_engine("klaR")
```

And a QDA using

```
QDA <- discrim_regularized(frac_common_cov = 0) %>% set_engine("klaR")`
```

I want ti run them both against a df using fit_resamples() to train it and collect_metric() to compare their perfomance against each other.

I have wrote the following code

```
rec <-
  recipe(~., data = df) 

mm <- discrim_regularized(frac_common_cov = 1) %>%
  set_engine("klaR")

fit <- 
  workflow() %>% 
  add_model(mm) %>% 
  add_recipe(rec) %>% 
  fit_resamples(
    resamples = rs,
    control = control_resamples(save_pred = TRUE)
  ) 
collect_metrics(fit)
```

But I am getting `All models failed.`

What am I missing?

Comment: This looks very hard to answer without a reproducible example. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example